# Limit $\lim _{ \theta \to 0 }{ \frac { cos2\theta -cos\theta }{ \theta } } $

Tags: calculus

$$\lim _{ \theta \to 0 }{ \frac { cos2\theta -cos\theta  }{ \theta  }  } $$

Steps I took:

$$\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 1-2sin^{ 2 }\theta -cos\theta  }{ \theta  }  } =$$

$$\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { -2sin^{ 2 }\theta  }{ \theta  }  } +\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 1-cos\theta  }{ \theta  }  } $$

$$\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 1-cos\theta  }{ \theta  } =0 } $$

$$\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { -2(sin\theta )(sin\theta ) }{ \theta  } = } $$

$$\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ { \quad -2(sin\theta ) }\cdot 1=0 } $$

$$0+0=0$$

Something seems off about the way I went about this but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Fixed. Is the rest correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your proof is correct. but if you are going to use $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{1-\cos \theta}{\theta} = 0,$ you could have split $\cos(2\theta) - \cos \theta$ as $(1-\cos \theta) -(1 - \cos 2 \theta)$ at the beginning itself.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hospital is very efficient here: just by inspection, $\dfrac{-0+0}1$.

Also, as the numerator is an even smooth function, it must be quadratic in $\theta$, hence $0$.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll do if you need to calcualte $\dfrac{\cos\pi\theta-\cos\dfrac32\theta}{\theta}$?

Following method encompasses such possibilities as well.

Use [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formula,

$$\cos(2m\theta)-\cos(2n\theta)=-2\sin(m+n)\theta\sin(m-n)\theta$$

and $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}h=1$

Here $2m=2,2n=1$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 1-cos\theta  }{ \theta }}=\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 2 \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} }{ \theta  } =0 }$$

Answer (score 0):

**Just to give you an other way to calculate your limit among these good answers**

$\cos\theta=1-\frac{\theta^2}{2}+ o(\theta^2)$ if $\theta\to 0$, and thus
$$\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\cos 2\theta-\cos \theta}{\theta}=\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{1-\frac{4\theta^2}{2}-1+\frac{\theta^2}{2}}{\theta}=\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{-3\theta}{2}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the symmetry:

$$\frac{\cos2\theta-\cos\theta}\theta=\frac{\cos2\theta-1}{\theta}-\frac{\cos\theta-1}\theta=\frac{2\sin^2\theta}{\theta}-\frac{2\sin^2\frac\theta2}{\theta}\to0-0$$